# rename all files in a folder with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

Can I rename all files in a folder with a batch file I tried this but it doesn't work

```
for %%a in (*.*) do ren sdel%random%.sdel %%a
```

and I also tryed

```
ren *.????? sdel%random%.sdel
```

Neither work what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks just like the question you asked on dostips and I told you twice you had the rename backwards.

Comment: If you are Ok with c++, I can do it. This is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
if not "%~nx0"=="%%a" ren "%%a" "sdel!random!.sdel"
)
```

Within a for loop, you should use EnableDelayedExpansion and use ! instead of % for variables. Note that I also added a if check so you don't rename the batch-file itself. If you wouldn't do that it would rename the batch-file, then be unable to find itself, and not rename any other files.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, but if the file name contains a space the code doesn't change it is there a way around this?

Comment: if a path may contain spaces, put quotes around it (or be consequent and put them around any path or filename): `ren "%%~a" "sdel!random!.sdel"`

Comment: If you feel like my answer solved your problem, you should click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct